# How to amplify laptop speakers?

Tags: technology, sound

I've a laptop (MBPR) and usually I'm watching movies on my second monitor which is far from my main laptop making the sound a bit low. And I don't want to buy external speakers, as the existing are not so bad.

There are some life hack of putting cut a solo cup in half to create a pair of makeshift amps, but [it simply doesn't work](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fQlYYZQBM4#t=349):)

Are there any other reliable life hacks of amplifying laptop speakers?

[image: Turn Solo Cups into Laptop Speaker Amplifiers]

P.S. I don't want to use any applications such as [Boom](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/) (not too mentioned you've to pay for these).

Comment: I run the same type of setup, I did not realize that my second monitor had speakers, until I accidentally hit the setup button and saw a sound option. You might want to double check your monitor for speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invest in **audio speakers** (Audio Jack or USB), that's the easiest way.

If you don't like wires, try **Bluetooth speakers**.

Alternatively you can use the **touch/induction speakers** which boosts the volume of any device with an external speaker. Place the device close to an external speaker for instant sound.

How does it work? It's grabbing the magnetic field of the speaker using induction, and then running that signal into its own amp and speakers.

If you're after hacky hardware solutions, try to **make your own induction speakers** as it doesn't look so complex.

See: [How The Mysterious Boost Connection-Less Speaker Works](http://www.cultofmac.com/152391/how-the-mysterious-boost-connection-less-speaker-works-review/)

[image: The Boost runs on three AA batteries]

Answer (score 3):

I affected sound output on my laptop by downloading a sound amplifier program. Search Google for "laptop amplifier download". Try several to see which works best. Run downloaded files through https://www.virustotal.com/ before installation to make sure they're safe.

My experience was pretty good. Output was probably fifty percent increased, but some of the sounds flattened out indicating the circuit was being over-driven a bit. Such does not cause damage, but volume may need to be reduced slightly to sound better. The one I used was trial-ware, meaning it worked for awhile with an occasional pop-up annoyance, then required payment. I chose to get cheap speakers, wanting better sound quality, and uninstalled the software.

You can try setting the laptop on its side in an attempt to direct output where you are sitting, which helps.

Answer (score 3):

Even more important than volume, when it comes to sound quality, is bandwidth (the range between the lowest and highest frequencies that can be reproduced by an audio system).

Even if they have excellent sound cards, built-in speaker subsystems found on laptops –even those of expensive macs– usually have bad performance at the lowest frequencies, because they are too small.

And if you put some plastic on top of them, you are not only redirecting the sound towards your position, but in the process also cutting the higher frequencies, or even introducing some distortion due to vibrations. But you are in no way "amplifying" sound.

It's simple, lower frequencies require more power than higher frequencies to perform at the same (audible) volume level (that's why sub woofers are much bigger than than satellite speakers on home theaters, for example).

You don't need to buy an expensive (>100 USD) set of speakers or home theater; even a cheap set of amplified desktop speakers (~5 USD) will sound a lot better than plastic cup halves vibrating on top of your laptop. But if you can afford a 2.1 set (with a decent sub-woofer, ~30 USD) just don't hesitate, it's an extremely huge difference, and you'll really start to enjoy audio quality.